# MVC project stops working when I move sln file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, project, solution, sln-file

I have created an MVC project and installed umbraco 7 through my VS2013

Upon creation if I choose 'Create directory for solution' then VS place sln file in the newly project folder and creates an internal folder where it places the project files. Not acceptable for me so I didn't tick 'Create directory for solution'.

Instead it places project files under new folder and the sln file outside this folder.

Now, I want to move sln file to the same folder where my files are located. I was always doing that with webforms projects and there was no problem.

With MVC project if I delete sln file VS created my MVC stops working, eg.
* I have no option Add > Controller when adding new item to Controller folder
* I have no option Add > Class when adding new item to Models folder and if creating standard classes under Models folder (eg. Add > New item > Class) those model classes cannot be seen by my views and controllers

Basically it breaks the MVC project.

It doesn't help if I save the project with new solution .sln file. And this file is not named by the project name (folder name) but as some localhost_[numbers].sln. Still it doesn't help and MVC is broken.

I would simply like move sln file to my project folder or delete it and create new one under the project folder.

Is it doable?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should know that VS solution is the way that VS organize your projects, that is why if you move it to another location you project does not work fine, I usually choose to create the solution first and the I add the projects I Need, I think that's what you need to do.

Saludos...Ing. Jorge Perez Barcenas

Comment: It worked perfectly well for my webforms projects, it doesn't work for mvc project